# NetBeans git merge failed. It say I have local modify and 'review' show nothing

Tags: git, netbeans, merge

I fetch the branch and merge it in the unchanged branch, but I couldn't merge it with my branch. It say I have local modified in local working directory, then I click 'review' and it show nothing (It mean no modified files, right?)

I have try git diff local branch with remote branch and it show no file too.
I also try to fetch + rebase this branch and it say the same as git merge say.

What wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If the error message is:

```
error: Untracked working tree file '...' would be overwritten by merge.
```

It would be best to revert to the command-line (outside Netbeans), and check if you can stash your current untracked modifications.
(Since [`git stash` isn't yet supported by NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=224986))